# How to get last part of URL to process in parent directory without creating a new child directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a url similar to:

`https://example.com/event/FI42382`

I have created a folder named `event` from which I want to use PHP to process the `FI42382` part.

However, the last part is treated as its own directory.  What do I need to do so that it is not a directory and instead I can manipulate the last path as a variable in `event/index.php`?

Sorry if I have worded the title poorly.  I wasn't sure how to explain this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass value which you want to access through a query string to your index.php etc. In your .htaccess file try with following Rules once. Also make sure place your .htaccess file in root(same level along with your `event` folder is present, NOT inside event folder please). Later in your php code you could get/extract the `var` value which is passed to it.

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^event/(.*)/?$ event/index.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```